# Spatial Reference not working with If-Else

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.4, if-else

I'm attempting to use a script to check a folder of data sets to see if they match a projection of another data set in a target folder. I need to be able to re project any that don't match the same projection as the file in the target folder and then copy the datasets to a projected folder. If the projections do match I need to copy this to the projected folder without re projecting.

I'm coming unstuck with my if/else statement at line 28 where:

```
if srcDesc.SpatialReference.Name == targetDesc.SpatialReference.Name:
```

When i run the script via a custom toolbox in Arcmap 10.4 i get the following error:

```
***line 27, in <module>

 if srcDesc.SpatialReference.Name==targetDesc.SpatialReference.Name:
AttributeError: DescribeData: Method SpatialReference does not exist***
```

My code is not perfect in other areas and I'm hoping someone may be able to help me work out where I've gone wrong?
Please excuse the over excessive commenting also :)

I'm thinking my error is something to do with describing the two datasets and with the `spatialReference` usage.

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy
import os

# Get input, target projection and output locations
datasetFolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
targetProjectionDataset = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
projectedDataset = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

# set workspace to the dataset folder
arcpy.env.workspace = datasetFolder

# returns a list of files in the dataset folder
for inputFC in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():

    # Use AddMessage to print feature classes in dataset folder
    arcpy.AddMessage("Datasets in the dataset folder are: " + str(inputFC))

    # describe the dataset in the dataset folder
    srcDesc = arcpy.Describe(inputFC)

    # describe the target dataset
    targetDesc = arcpy.Describe(targetProjectionDataset)

    outputFC = projectedDataset

    # test for matching coord systems
    if srcDesc.SpatialReference.Name == targetDesc.SpatialReference.Name:
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(inputFC, outputFC)
    else:
        # set the output name to match the input name
        outputNewFC = os.path.join(projectedDataset, inputFC)

        # Set projection to be used
        outCS = arcpy.SpatialReference(targetDesc)

        # run projection tool
        arcpy.Project_management(datasetFolder, outputNewFC, outCS)

        # check messages
        print(arcpy.GetMessages())
```

Comment: it needs to be `srcDesc.spatialReference.Name` with the "S" being lowercase as it is a class property.

Comment: Thanks mate! Turns out I didn't have the correct parameters set when I added my script to my custom tool box :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a test with this code and it worked (tested in Python terminal in Arcgis 10.3)

```
import arcpy
src1 = r"D:\layer1.shp"
src2 = r"D:\layer2.shp"
srcDesc1 = arcpy.Describe(src1)
srcDesc2 = arcpy.Describe(src2)
if srcDesc1.spatialReference.Name == srcDesc2.spatialReference.Name:
    print("match")
else:
    print("no match")
```

I already knew the results would produce *no match* as the CRS are different. I also tried using layers with matching CRS and the results were *match*.

In this code I have used .spatialReference.Name with a lower case *s* as referenced on this [site](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/the-spatial-reference-object.htm).

Comment: You could also use the factoryCode property which is an integer value. Just as an alternative.

Comment: @tsvGis Thanks for the help. I had some parameters set incorrectly within my Arc custom toolbox! I fixed those and it seems to work. Thank-you again!

Comment: @dslamb Using the factory code actually worked first attempt for me once I got my toolbox parameters correct! Thanks so much for the knowledge!!